# My ubuntu 20.04 hangs when ever I open any application

Tags: 20.04, freeze, menu

I am unable to use any application after I click menu option before it everything was fine. A red circle with a white cross appears on the leftmost top corner. Every application is opened but I am not able to use it. On clicking this cross, the application closes.

This started yesterday. Have experienced the same issue a couple of times, it resolves after reboot.

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks